# Passing Variables to a Windows SSH Server

Tags: windows, unix, ssh, openssh

I am trying to pass a variable to a windows SSH server. For some reason it is not reading it and giving me a "The specified path is invalid." error. The code I am running is

`$filepath="C:\\temp"`

`ssh user@server "dir /b $filepath"`

With unix I am able to pass a variable this way, but I am not sure why it does not work with windows. Thanks!

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Stack Overflow is specifically for programming problems. This isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `c:\temp` instead of `c:\\temp` and make sure the folder exists